# Evitar erro ao recuperar campo do Json

Tags: php

Bom preciso fazer um tratamento de um erro ao recuperar um campo de um json.

Tenho o seguinte Json:

```
{
    "Autenticacao": {
        "login": "123",
        "senha": "123"
    }
}
```

Estou recuperando os dados assim:

```
// Decodifica o Json
$obj = json_decode($json);

$obj->autenticacao->login;
```

Até aqui tudo bem, o problema é quando o usuário informa um json que contenha um array, assim:

```
{
    "Autenticacao": [{
        "login": "123",
        "senha": "123"
    }]
}
```

Com isso o php dá o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Que ocorre na linha:

```
$obj->autenticacao->login;
```

Como posso tratar esse erro e informar para o usuário que o json não esta correto.

Comment: Devias ter isso constante, ou recebes de uma maneira, ou de outra... Nunca com essa imprevisibilidade. Ou há alguma razão para isso?

Comment: Isso é contante, porém se alguém do Front-end esquecer é mandar errado eu quero tratar o erro, evitando o erro no php e a criação de um log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que você faça a verificação para saber se o elemento é ou não um `array`, porém caso seja um array seria ideal você verificar se existe apenas um chave (caso o front-end envie um array com duas chaves).

```
$raw = '{"Autenticacao": {"login": "123","senha": "123"}}';
$json = json_decode($raw);

var_dump(is_array($json->Autenticacao) && count($json->Autenticacao) > 1);
// Saida: bool(false)
```

No exemplo acima, caso seja um `array` e seja um array possua mais que um indice então retorno um `erro` de dados inválidos.

```
$raw = '{"Autenticacao": [{"login": "123","senha": "123"}]}';
$json = json_decode($raw);

var_dump(is_array($json->Autenticacao) && count($json->Autenticacao) > 0);
// Saida: bool(true)
```

No exemplo acima caso seja `true` atribua os valores a outras variaveis;

```
if (is_array($json->Autenticacao) && count($json->Autenticacao) === 1) {
    $login = $json->Autenticacao[0]->login;
    $senha = $json->Autenticacao[0]->senha;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, vlw.

Answer (score 2):

Sendo assim, podes evitar originar um erro da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "Autenticacao": [{
        "login": "123",
        "senha": "123"
    }]
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
if(!isset($obj->Autenticacao->login)) { // aqui verificamos se a propriedade existe
    die('error brrrhh'); //  erro aqui,usuário informa um json que contenha um array
}
echo $obj->Autenticacao->login; // está tudo bem
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/a7ptev) a correr mal

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/WvWAA0) a correr bem

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado